# Which PHP accelerator to use with prefork mpm (CentOS and RedHat default httpd settings)

Tags: php

As you know, even if it is possible to start httpd in worker mode under CentOS/RedHat, php in default rpm repo is not thread-safe. And the default configuration for stability is mpm_prefork. So, two questions:

- Is there PHP accelerator capable of working in mpm_prefork mode (using shm or whatever)?
- If there is none, what can be done to improve PHP speed on CentOS/RedHat systems (I want to use rpms, preferably from default CentOS repo; building custom PHP from source code is not a good option for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using php <5.3, apc, xcache, eacellerator will all work with prefork.  Some require the php5-dev libraries to be installed which should be packaged already, and the opcode caches may already be prepackaged for you.

If you wanted to use worker, you can use fcgid or fastcgi to handle php which would allow you to use worker, and would spawn php-cgi processes to handle your php files.

Comment: Is, for example, APC effective in prefork? It seems, that it will store php cache per process, right? And each time php-cgi is called, the cache is rebuild, effectively removing all speed-up.